# Oracle restore dmp to existing database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I wish to restore Oracle database from .dmp file.

When I try to import this file it doesn't replace current data.
The suggestion on forum is to drop user/schema and then import .dmp. 
But I don't want to do it because everything is working under System user. 
So if I drop system user i'll lose access to database management.

Any ideas how to import .dmp file and replace current data ?

Comment: Why have you created anything under the built-schemas? Never do that... You should have your own user/schema to work under. And you can import into a different schema than the data was exported from.

Comment: And this shows why using the SYSTEM schema for our work is considered bad practice. Which obviously doesn't help you, but this is an important teaching.

Comment: @barbarosozhan - I don't know why you decided to tag this question with `[datapump]`. The OP has given no indication that they are using that feature rather than the old skool EXP and IMP command line utilities. Obviously it would be helpful if the OP had clarified their question to state which approach they are using. Given that they appear not to know that this matters inclines me to think they don't know there's more than one way to export and import schemas, from which I deduce they are using IMP and EXP. But only they no for sure.

Comment: @APC Well, I leant on the file extension ( `.dmp` ).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - but that tells us nothing. `.dmp` is a generic file extension. EXP dumps to `.dmp` too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using datapump, I think you will have to consider parameter [`TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-C9664F8C-19C5-4177-AC20-5682AEABA07F.htm#SUTIL936)

It seems you can use `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE` to suits your need but be careful if there are SYSTEM tables in your dump file, better target the tables where you want to replace data using the `TABLES=...` clause.

*P.S. This way you can refresh the tables and their data exactly, but unfortunately not possible to refresh the other existing objects such as functions, procedures, packages ... etc. without dropping and recreating them through datapump import.*